# Php Core error after uploading to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an error while uploading a completed project to server

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/dba.so' - libtokyocabinet.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

Can anyone please help me to understand what this error means and how I can debug this?

Comment: When do you get this? Startup or page access? What version of PHP are you using? Where are you uploading it to? Please add some information in the question to give people some guidelines to help you.

Comment: Looks like you're relying on `libtokyocabinet` and that simply isn't available on the destination server. Have you got control over that server enough to install it?

Comment: first of all sorry for late replay @Tom i get error in all pages i use php 7

Comment: @Rob Forrest  no i don't have control over the server so should i contact server administrator for installing

Comment: That depends, are you using ToykoCabinet? More than likely, the people you are hosting with will have a MySQL/MariaDB server that you can use instead.